# problem creating new column in mySQL / phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a mySQL table in phpMyAdmin (in the server), and I'm having problems to create and save a new column.

The table name is 'visage', it exists and it has already the following variables:

```
ind1    int(15)
lien1   varchar(2083)
dire    text
ind2    ind(15)
lien2   varchar(2083)
delta   int(15)
```

I want to add a new column called 'inddir' where values will depend  on values in columns 'ind1' and 'dire', by using SELECT/CASE/WHEN:

```
SELECT *,

CASE

  WHEN `dire` = 'der' THEN ((ind1*10)+0)

  WHEN `dire` = 'izq' THEN ((ind1*10)+1)

  WHEN `dire` = 'del' THEN ((ind1*10)+2)

  WHEN `dire` = 'atr' THEN ((ind1*10)+3)

  WHEN `dire` = 'arr' THEN ((ind1*10)+4)

  WHEN `dire` = 'abj' THEN ((ind1*10)+5)

END AS `inddir`

FROM `visage`
```

This request is not working:

--> in phpMyAdmin: https://ibb.co/54GpX4N

I obtain the errors, directly in the code: "Unrecognized keyword.(near AS)" and "Unexpected token. (near `inddir`)   https://ibb.co/1ZZ4rc1

BUT, when I do not use "AS `indir`", mySQL creates a new column the way I want, but with a name that is the complete query --> and I'm not able to SAVE this column.

--> in phpMyAdmin:  https://ibb.co/PY82Kwq

Can somebody tell my how I can create the `inddir` column as expected, and then being able to SAVE this new column in the mySQL table?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Working perfectly fine here: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gomfd1tHLmApQSW6HAWhvq/0

Comment: thank you Madhur, but as I show in the pictures, the same code is not workigng in phpMyAdmin (  https://ibb.co/54GpX4N  and  https://ibb.co/1ZZ4rc1 ), Thank you anyway for taking the time to try.

Answer (score 0):

I use heidiSQL and it works with me. Can you try both below versions, with and without 'AS' keyword?

```
SELECT *,
case
    when `currency` = 'USD' then 7
    when `currency` = 'EUR' then 8
    when `currency` = 'JPY' then 9
END as `newcolum`
FROM accounts;

SELECT *,
case
    when `currency` = 'USD' then 7
    when `currency` = 'EUR' then 8
    when `currency` = 'JPY' then 9
END 
FROM accounts;
```

Comment: Thank you Aris, but your first option is not working in my case (please see --> https://ibb.co/54GpX4N and the error https://ibb.co/1ZZ4rc1) and your second option is working, but it generates a column where the name is the entire request, and I can not save it into the database...

Comment: seems like heidiSQL behaves differently than phpMyAdmin, because for me it selects as expected.